# pid from fork() never goes to parent, only child

Tags: c, process, fork, parent

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include "structs.h"
#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"


int main(void)
{

  pid_t pid;
  int mypipe[2];
  int otherPipe[2];

  if(pipe(mypipe))
    {
      printf("Error in making a pipe");
    }
  if(pipe(otherPipe))
    {
      printf("Error creating another pipe");
    }
  if((pid=fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }
  printf("Child ID: %d" , pid);
  if(pid == 0)
    {
      close(mypipe[1]);
      close(otherPipe[0]);
      client *c = new client(mypipe[0], otherPipe[1]);
      wait(NULL);
      //c->startProgram();
      //return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Yo");
    close(mypipe[0]);
    close(otherPipe[1]);
    server s;
    s.fdIn = otherPipe[0];
    s.fdOut = mypipe[1];
    s.startServer();
    //wait(NULL);
    //return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Above is my code.  The child process runs fine (If I remove that comment obviously), however the else never gets executed (Or am I missing something in the terminal?).

Here's a screen shot of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MawUJ.png

Any ideas on why it's not going to the else/parent spot?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you expect? What does `strace` tells you?

Comment: Why are you `wait`ing in the child??

Comment: I don't know what strace is and how to use it.  I'll look in to it when I have some more time though.  And I actually switched the parent with the child earlier and left that there.  Thought it might have reached the parent before the child.  My bad.  Removing it didn't help though.  It seems to be Michael K. was correct.  Thanks for looking though!

Comment: If you expect output to appear on the screen, end the output with a newline, or force it out with `fflush()`.  When your messages do not end with a newline, they remain buffered until the buffer overfills or a newline is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be because `stdio` is buffered? Try flushing output after `printf`ing the child id. Or adding a `\n`. Or `fprintf`ing it to `stderr`.

*EDIT*: Just to clarify. My guess is not that it's the reason it's not getting to parent, for it is, it is why you do not see the output you expect.

Comment: I agree with the idea of adding a \n for the printf.

Comment: Basically, all three should result into flushing it to the terminal, so I leave it up to OP to decide what suits him best ;-) (I'd also go for `\n` because the output looks prettier then.

Comment: That works... Can you explain why this is?  Like, what prevents the process from starting because I printed something without a new line at the end?

Comment: @JustinWarner, I was just in time to edit my answer and add the clarification ;-)

Comment: So it wouldn't output the "Yo" beacuse it never had a newline/clear buffer to send it through because of the above?

Comment: @JustinWarner The parent is already started, so nothing can prevent it from starting. All that happened is that you didn't see the printf output, and then you rashly assumed things from there. A common rookie error is having a mental model such that the output specified by a printf happens at the point that the printf is called.

Comment: Yes, it would output `Yo` into internal buffers, but never flush it to the terminal, because `stdout` is line-buffered.